# crontab job occasionally quits without explanation

Tags: python, bash, perforce, cron

I have a crontab job that runs hourly. Sometimes it quits early without explanation, or reason I can discern. What might be the problem? What might help me dig deeper?

The context is Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. SHELL is /bin/bash.

The job definition is presently:

```
59 * * * * set -x; set +e; cd ~/OPEN/staging-site ; /usr/local/bin/p4 sync -q ; bin/publish.py ...
```

(the "set"s are part of my current debugging work).

The resulting email, when it fails, with some headers pruned, is:

```
From: Cron Daemon <root@HERE.com>
To: "Repenning, Jack" <jrepenni@HERE.com>
Content-Class: urn:content-classes:message
Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 14:57:01 -0600
Subject: Cron <jrepenni@prod-akiary-app01> set -x; set +e; cd  ~/OPEN/staging-site ; /usr/local/bin/p4 sync  -q ; bin/staging
x-cron-env: <LOGNAME=jrepenni>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0

+ set +e
+ cd /u0/jrepenni/OPEN/staging-site
+ /usr/local/bin/p4 sync -q
```

Note that there's no mention of launching `bin/staging`. Confirming this, there are side effects that would be found, such as creating a tmp directory for its work, if even the most minimal execution of `bin/staging` happened. No such traces.

I happen to know that the Perforce API returns an error for some things that no rational being would consider errors (such as "you requested a sync but were already in sync"). This does not seem to extend to the command line, which returns no-error (0) in this case. But, what the heck, I tried the `set +e` in case such a spurious error return was halting the script. No help.

The script `bin/staging` takes care of $PATH and such cron-required niceties -- but, of course, it doesn't even get launched, so that's neither here nor there.

UPDATE: The script is executable:

```
> ll bin/staging 
-r-xr-xr-x 1 jrepenni users 251 Jan 17 11:55 bin/staging
```

... and shabanged:

```
> head -1 bin/staging
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Check /var/log/cron for some more info maybe? Also maybe specify a full path to bin/staging instead of a relative path?

Comment: Got no /var/log/cron. /var/log/syslog records the launch of the command but no indication of success or failure I can see:

Comment: Add this to the end of your cronjob: `> /tmp/mylog.txt 2>&1` and see what you get.

Comment: The same as I was getting in email

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that things are breaking in perforce since that is where it stops.  It could help to merge STDERR into your output by adding `2>&1` to you `p4 sync`.

Putting your code into a script and running it repeatedly could you trip over the issue interactively.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm: either I misspoke, or behavior is variable.

I now see those external traces, indicating that the bin/staging script does run. Cron job email sill stops at the p4 line, but this seems to be an I/O problem, not an actual execution one. Possibly ssh is at fault (in  our config, p4 talks to its repository via ssh tunnel).

Whatever's going on, it changed last night; I had been getting regular output from the bin/staging process, and suddenly not.

Thanks, all, for the labor of your "little grey cells."